# Position CSS element based on height of a floating element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alright, this one's tricky.

To begin, this fix can be in JS or CSS, doesn't matter as long as it works.

Here's the issue:
I have a site with a float:right sidebar, and the footer's position is based on the #content's height. However, when the #content is shorter than the sidebar, the footer overlaps the sidebar and doesn't look very good.

What I need:
a script that detects the HEIGHT of a certain element (in this case #sidebar) and modifies the min-height of the #content to match

OR

a script that detects the HEIGHT of the #sidebar and positions the footer accordingly.

For a live version of this, check http://wizardcm.com/portfolio

The reason for not using a fixed height for the #content (or for the position of the footer) is that Tweets are never the same length, and other pages have extra sidebar widgets that add to the height.

Comment: I really don't see the problem, just resize it onload or resize?

Comment: @StefanDenchev I couldn't find a script to do so, and I'm not skilled in JS. Got a link?

Comment: The point of this community is to learn and become better at programming, not copy/paste snippets of code

Comment: If any of the answers below helped solve your issue or you think they answer your question, you should consider marking one of them (unfortunately can't do more :P) as answer.

Comment: @ile I understand that, however much testing & troubleshooting went into trying to get this to work without outside help. After much messing around, asking friends to tinker, and **so much** Google'ing, I decided I finally needed help from a community that was known for quick and helpful suggestions and fixes - which is exactly what I received. Sometimes you just need an outside perspective to fix something you're overlooking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.put your `#sidebar` before `#content`.
2.remove `position:absolute` from `#sidebar`.
3.remove `float:left` from `#content`.
4.remove `overflow:hidden` from `#content`.

Comment: In previous attempts I have messed with trying to have the sidebar before the content, but everything I tried ended up with the sidebar on top and the content below. CSS can be so fiddly sometimes. Thanks for the direct, simple, and to-the-point response. If I can't get @keeg's code working, I'll try yours. I just hate messing with getting sidebars properly working with WordPress' PHP.

Comment: fixed width and float:left is not a better way. it will cause your sidebar to jump down in smaller windows.

Comment: Well, after some (very quick) testing, your suggestion works perfectly based on my needs. It has now been implemented. Thanks again for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

> What I need: a script that detects the HEIGHT of a certain element (in
>   this case #sidebar) and modifies the min-height of the #content to
>   match

Make sure you link jQuery in your `head` tag... example:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Than place the following code within a `<script>` tag below it:

```
$(window).bind("resize", function(){
    var $sideHeight = $("#sidebar").height();
    $("#content").css({minHeight: $sideHeight + 'px'});
}).trigger("resize");
```

Comment: Just tried this, and got this error in Chrome's Dev Tools (console)



Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function portfolio:65
(anonymous function) portfolio:65
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Comment: Do you have jQuery linked on the page?

Comment: Updated answer, you have to load up jQuery first in the head.

Comment: [This](http://ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=609) might help :P.

Comment: Hmm, I was sure I had jQuery running.. maybe that was only on the homepage. I'll have to play around with jQuery more then, as it has been useful in the past. Thanks though, this does help in furthering my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with your css layout, you do not need a JavaScript solution. You have floats and absolute positioning on your sidebar which takes it out of page flow.

Your classes should be:

```
#content {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 770px;
}

#sidebar {
    float: right;
    font-size: 10pt;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
    right: 40px;
    width: 300px;
}

#content .page, #content .post {
    padding: 10px 15px !important;
}
```

And everything falls into place.

Comment: You wouldn't believe how much time I spent messing around with trying to get the elements to align properly. Even with a friend looking over the code, it took multiple revisions to get the code working close to how I wanted it. At one point we even had a solid white 'sidebarback' 10000px tall element to try and correct it. I fixed that issue in the end, but it's still not perfect. Thanks for this snippet, I'll test yours first, as @rishabhgoel's would require messing with WordPress PHP and I've done that enough already.

Comment: After getting a chance to review your suggestion and test it within Chrome, it fulfils the question asked, however at the loss of the fluid configuration of #content. Thanks again for your suggestion, but I'll be going with @rishabhgoel's version as it follows with the fluid design I'm going for.